# Does the pagespeed test score take CDN into consideration?

Tags: cdn, pagespeed

I set up CDN for Global acceleration, after checking, I find the speed score of the mobile device is still low. so I wonder if the score takes CDN into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it takes CDN into consideration.

Firstly, you need to understand that for Google PageSpeed mobile test has network limits and probably slowed down CPU power. The network limits for mobile tests are something like this:

> - Latency: 150ms
> - Throughput: 1.6Mbps down / 750 Kbps up.
> - Packet loss: none
>
> These exact figures are used as Lighthouse's throttling default and
>   represent roughly the bottom 25% of 4G connections and top 25% of 3G
>   connections. They are identical to the WebPageTest "Mobile 3G - Fast"
>   preset and, due to a lower latency, slightly faster for some pages
>   than the WebPageTest "4G" preset.

Source: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/throttling.md

As there are these network limits, if your CDN is a bit faster in general then your server, you probably won't notice much difference in speed in the Google Page Speed mobile as the tests already are done with network limits to make the tests more real for real mobile world.

Secondly, if you looking at Field Data, you should give a time for these data, as these data are from real users and are based on the previous 30 days of data. If you have these data available for your website, I would recommend taking a screenshot and comparing these data after 30 days to see does it helped to you.

In meantime, there are many other things to do with higher priority.

**Bonus tip to improve CDN speed: Use Resource Hints: DNS Prefetch and/or Preconnect**

As CDN is a 3rd party domain and host, it's recommended to pre-connect to the CDN server, so your recourses could be loaded sooner after your basic HTML is loaded and the client is starting to load the first recourse from your CDN network.

The code what you should add on your head as high as possible should look like this:

```html
<!-- Prefetch DNS for external assets -->
 <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//cdn.example.com">

<!-- Preconnect for external assets -->
 <link rel="preconnect" href="//cdn.example.com" crossorigin>
```